# How is IQ-modulation done on the digital side rather than the analog side?

Tags: modulation, demodulation, frequency-modulation, quadrature

The original way of doing In-phase Quadrature (IQ) modulation is by modulating and mixing on the analog side. I have read that as the digital processing have gotten better, the modulation and mixing may be done on the digital side before going into the DAC.

I have not found a lot of information about this and would like to know more of how it is done.

I found [a post](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/technical-articles/should-i-and-q-combining-and-separation-be-done-digitally-or-analogly/) about this. But I do not fully understood as it seem to skip some, for me, essential information.

How is the data IQ-modulated/demodulated on the digital side?

[image: https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/technical-articles/should-i-and-q-combining-and-separation-be-done-digitally-or-analogly/]

Comment: Are you able to narrow your question to what specifically in that referenced article that confuses you? Just so someone doesn’t repeat everything that is already there which already seems to answer you question.

Comment: Meaning is it just a particular item in that block diagram that you want further details on as it shows all the required pieces: filtering, quadrature oscillator, multipliers, combiner, DAC- what doesn’t make sense or is still confusing?

Comment: Pretty much exactly what's in that block diagram -- what are you having difficulty interpreting?